# C# lock with LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, synchronization, thread-safety

Is it necessary to lock LINQ statements as follows? If omitting the lock, any exceptions will be countered when multiple threads execute it concurrently?

```
lock (syncKey)
{
    return (from keyValue in dictionary
            where keyValue.Key > versionNumber
            select keyValue.Value).ToList();
}
```

PS: **Writer** threads do exist to mutate the dictionary.

Comment: As a side note, if you didn't have the ToList() at the end, you would need the lock when you *iterate* over the collection, not here where you just return it.

Answer (score 6):

So long as the query has no side-effects (such as any of the expressions calling code that make changes) there there is no need to lock a LINQ statement.

Basically, if you don't modify the data (and nothing else is modifying the data you are using) then you don't need locks.

If you are using .NET 4.0 and there is a ConcurrentDictionary that is thread safe. [Here is an example of using a concurrent dictionary](http://colinmackay.scot/blog/2011/03/24/parallelisation-in-net-4-0-the-concurrent-dictionary/) (admittedly not in a LINQ statement)

**UPDATE**

If you are modifying data then you need to use locks. If two or more threads attempt to access a locked section of code there will be a small performance loss as one or more of the threads waits for the lock to be released. NOTE: If you over-lock then you may end up with worse performance that you would if you had just built the code using a sequential algorithm from the start.

If you are only ever reading data then you don't need locks as there is no mutable shared state to protect.

If you do not use locks then you may end up with intermittent bugs where the data is not quite right or exceptions are thrown when collisions occur between readers and writers. In my experience, most of the time you may never get an exception, you just get corrupt data (except you don't necessarily know it is corrupt). Here is another example showing [how data can be corrupted if you don't use locks or redesign your algorithm to cope](http://colinmackay.scot/blog/2011/05/25/building-messages-in-parallel/).

You often get the best out of a system if you consider the constraints of developing in a parallel system from the outset. Sometimes you can re-write your code so it uses no shared data. Sometime you can split the data up into chunks and have each thread/task work on its own chunk then have some process at the end stitch it all back together again.

Comment: Hi Colin, if a reader thread is interrupted by a writer or conversely, will any excpetion arise?

Comment: What do you mean by "interrupted"?

Comment: Do you mean: What if something writes while something else reads? If so, then the results are undefined. It may break. It may not. It may result in inconsistent data. It really depends on the exact point the writer gets control. Multi-threading is one of the greatest sources of non-deterministic/intermittent bugs. If you have readers AND writers then use locks... or rearchitect so you don't have readers and writers at the same time.

Comment: Your answer: It may break. Do you mean an exception will be thrown? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, or perhaps not. That's the non-deterministic nature of the beast. It may obviously break by causing something to throw an exception, or it may be very subtle that you don't notice until much later. If you have readers and writers use locks and suffer the small performance loss for safety. If you have only readers then don't use locks and take full advantage of multi-core/processor power.

Answer (score 6):

Most types are thread-safe to *read*, but not thread-safe during mutation.

If none of the threads is *changing* the dictionary, then you don't need to do *anything* - just read away.

If, however, one of the threads is *changing* it then you have problems and need to synchronize. The simplest approach is a `lock`, however this prevents concurrent readers even when there is no writer. If there is a good chance you will have more readers that writers, consider using a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to synchronize - this will allow any number of readers (with no writer), or: one writer.

In 4.0 you might also consider a [`ConcurrentDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)

Comment: Hi Marc, if a reader thread is interrupted by a writer or conversely, will any excpetion arise?

Comment: @Ricky: it won't be interrupted, the other thread will block (wait).

Comment: @Ricky - to confirm @zespri's comment - the writer will be blocked until the readers have all finished; the writer is exclusive

Comment: Sorry! My actual qustion is that without lock braces around. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If your dictionary is static and a method where you run the query is not (or another concurrent access scenarios), and dictionary can be modified from another thread, then yes, lock is required otherwise - is not.

Comment: it wouldn't have to be static - just accessible from multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to lock your shared resources when using LINQ in multi-threaded scenarios (EDIT: of course, if your source collection is being modified as Marc said, if you are only reading it, you don't need to worry about it). If you are using .Net 4 or the parallel extensions for 3.5 you could look at  replacing your Dictionary with a ConcurrentDictionary (or use some other custom implementation anyway).

Comment: No, you don't need to lock a dictionary in a multi-threaded scenario. You only need locking if you are modifying data in a multi-threaded scenario. If all threads are only reading the dictionary then everything is fine without the lock.

Comment: It seems you commented after my edit. I know it is thread-safe to read from most collections, it was just an oversight to ommit it at first.